# New novels — by turns salty, sweeping and sweet

Tags: word-meaning

Is the word "sweeping" a taste in English like salty and sweet? What does it mean then? Does it mean "overwhelming"? But "overwhelming" isn't a taste. I am confused.

> The Ultimate Summer Escape: Historical Fiction
> **New novels — by turns salty, sweeping and sweet** — will transport you to 1930s Italy, 19th-century England and San Francisco a hundred years ago.

Source: [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/05/27/books/new-historical-fiction.html?smtyp=cur&smid=tw-nytimes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rather a mixed metaphor, but in fact most of the meanings have nothing to do with taste directly.

- **Salty** means flavorful, full-bodied, perhaps emotionally deep—or possibly down-to-earth, salt-of-the-land (as *a salty sailor*).
- **Sweeping** means wide-ranging or broad, not "overwhelming" (probably).
- **Sweet** means pleasant, agreeable, charming, perhaps adorable.

The author is describing many different novels, and it is not necessary that they all be described the same way.

Comment: In this case I suspect 'salty' to be much closer to the last provided possibility, that 'rude' language is used.